# preg_match_all ignore words

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I try to create a regex to capture emails ending not .info/.con containing no aaa/bbb.

Is this the correct syntax?

```
Eg: // search email ending in .com/.info containing no aaa/bbb
preg_match_all('#((?=.*@.*(?:com|info))(!.*(?:aaa|bbb)).*)#ui', $html, $emails);
```

To get this:

```
caaac@ccc.com = no
ccc@ccbbb.com = no
cccc@cccc.com = good (address syntax correct + term absent before or after the @)
```

---

Thank you for your reply.

This syntax works fine [SEE HERE](http://lumadis.be/regex/test_regex.php?id=788) (thank you to STEMA) except for a string that includes spaces.

e.g:

```
$string = "email1@address.com blah email2@aaaaess.com blah email3@address.info embbbil4@adress.com";
preg_match_all("#^(?!.*aaa)(?!.*bbb).*@.*\.(?:com|info)$#im", $string, $matches);
```

Cordially

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution:

```
#(?<=^|\s)(?![\w@]*(?:aaa|bbb|(?:[0-9].*){3,}))[a-z0-9-_.]*@[a-z0-9-_.]*\.(?:com|net|org|info|biz)(?=\s|$)#im
```

Function:

```
function get_emails($str){
    preg_match_all('#(?<=^|\s)(?![\w@]*(?:aaa|bbb|(?:[0-9].*){3,}))[a-z0-9-_.]*@[a-z0-9-_.]*\.(?:com|net|org|info|biz)(?=\s|$)#im', $str, $output);
    if(is_array($output[0]) && count($output[0])>0) {
            return array_unique($output[0]);
        }
}
```

Cordially

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a positive expression and check that it did not match anything.

```
if (preg_match(...) == 0)
```

Also, there is no need to use `preg_match_all` if you are just interested whether a pattern matched or not.

Comment: There may be several e-mails to capture and not containing the prohibited words (aaa | bbb) in an HTML page to parse.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirements right, then this would be the regex you can use together with @Tomalak answer.

```
preg_match('#.*@.*(?:aaa|bbb)|\.(?:com|info)$#ui', $html, $emails);
```

This pattern matches the stuff you **don't** want.

`.*@.*(?:aaa|bbb)` matches aaa or bbb after the `@`

the `\.(?:com|info)$` is the other part, this matches if your email address ends with `.com` or `.info`

You can see it online [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2tu1m)

**Update:**

```
.*(?:aaa|bbb).*\.(?:com|info)$
```

This will match `aaa` or `bbb` and the string has to end with `.com` or `.info`

See it online [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2tu2h)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

Search terms can be before or after the at sign and surrounded by characters. eg: See above

Comment: @la_chouette I updated my answer, did I get the requirements right this time?

Comment: @stema First of all, thank you again for your help. It's almost that, I also try my hand: [HERE](http://lumadis.be/regex/test_regex.php?id=786)

Comment: almost `#(?!.*(?:aaa|bbb)).*@(?!.*(?:aaa|bbb)).*(?:.com|.info)#ui`

Comment: @la_chouette is it now working as expected? (or is there still something not OK)

Comment: @stema Partly, there's a bug on the 4th catch as you can see [here](http://lumadis.be/regex/test_regex.php?id=786). (tbbbt3@Test.info)

Comment: @la_chouette try this [here](http://lumadis.be/regex/test_regex.php?id=788). Its not necessary to repeat the lookaheads. And I think an important point are the anchors `^$` to force it to match from start to the end of the row. Therefor I added also the `m` modifier to make `$` match at the end of the row.

Comment: @stema Thank you I understand better.

However after putting into practice your syntax, it returns me nothing.

eg:
`$string = "email@address.com blah blah email2@ahostess.com blah email3@address.com email@adnsress.com";
preg_match_all("#^(?!.*host)(?!.*dns).*@.*\.(?:com|info)$#im", $string, $matches);
`